# how to effectively use strtok function

Tags: c, strtok

Yes, I'm a newbie as well. And I have been having this problem for quite some time. I'm trying to use strtok to split off a string, but the thing is it does not work. I have looked at the example on the man-pages as well as those online, and I still don't have the answer.

In the code below, I tried to use the sample code given as an answer in this site. The original while loop is:

```
    char str[] = "hello world how are you?\n";
    char *res;

    res = strtok(str, " \n");
    puts(res);
    while (res != NULL)
    {
        res = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        if(res!=NULL)
            puts(res);
    }
```

but when a change the str to data, and its respective delimiters (&=), it becomes a Segmentation Fault. How do I fix this? What's wrong in the code? Here is the complete code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *data;

    data = "integer1=1&integer2=2&integer3=3&integer4=4";
    puts(data);

    char str[] = "hello world how are you?\n";
    char *res;

    res = strtok(data, "=&");
    puts(res);
    while (res != NULL)
    {
        res = strtok(NULL, "=&");
        if(res!=NULL)
            puts(res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

by the way, the strtok_r function doesn't work either.

Comment: Also, please **insert a whitespace** between the `#include` directive and the file name, like this: `#include <string.h>`, and **not** `#include<string.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
char str[] = "hello world how are you?\n";
```

creates an array and initializes it with the contents of the string literal. This, however:

```
char *data;

data = "integer1=1&integer2=2&integer3=3&integer4=4";
```

declares `data` to be a pointer to the first character of the string literal, which is, of course, read-only, so when `strtok()` tries to modify it, it fails (invoking undefined behavior).

---

Notes:

1. So that's why you declare pointers to string literals as `const char *` and ***explicitly not as*** `char *`, and if you do so, I will find you and const-qualify you.
2. [Arrays are not pointers, they never were, and they never will be either.](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html)

Comment: @Ryaminal You mean "I will find you and `const`-qualify you?" :P

Comment: Aye, that one. Going to have nightmares of compilers attacking the world. Much scarier than zombies.

Comment: @Ryaminal Note that if you are `const`, you ain't fearin' any kompilerz, they can't hurt ya.

Comment: But if you const-qualify Rex, he won't be able to change his bad habits (such as trying to modify string literals).

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're observing can be explained by question 1.32 in [com.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html):

> What is the difference between these initializations?
>
> ```
> char a[] = "string literal";
> char *p  = "string literal";
> ```
>
> My program crashes if I try to assign a new value to p[i].

And the answer is:

> A string literal (the formal term for a double-quoted string in C source) can be used in two slightly different ways:
>
> 1. As the initializer for an array of char, as in the declaration of char a[] , it specifies the initial values of the characters in that array (and, if necessary, its size).
> 2. Anywhere else, it turns into an unnamed, static array of characters, and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified. In an expression context, the array is converted at once to a pointer, as usual (see section 6), so the second declaration initializes p to point to the unnamed array's first element.

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` break memory block. And literal strings can't modofiy. So you can't use `strtoke` for both.
Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *data;

    data = "integer1=1&integer2=2&integer3=3&integer4=4";
    char *cur, *res;

    cur = data;
    res = strpbrk(cur, "=&");
    while (res != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(cur, 1, res-cur, stdout);
        fputc('\n', stdout);

        cur = res + 1;
        res = strpbrk(cur, "=&");
    }
    fputs(cur, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't modify memory block.